# Why it is possible to access private const field from attribute?

Tags: c#, oop, attributes, encapsulation, private-members

How is it possible?

```
namespace test
    {
        class Attr:Attribute
        {
            public Attr(int e)
            {
            }
        }

        [Attr(E)]
        class Test
        {
            private const int E = 0;
        }
    }
```

Doesn't it violate encapsulation principle?

Comment: The attribute `Attr` is a member of the class `Test`. A member of a class has access to the private fields of that class.

Comment: You pass private field value into ctor of another class. What does this have to do with breaking encapsulation? Especially when you pass in value type.

Comment: Where can I read how it is working? Can you provide some links?@JeroenVannevel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this doesn't violate encapsulation. The attribute declaration is logically part of the class. `Attr` is not accessing `Test.E` (it can't), you are calling the constructor of `Attr` with `E` from within `Test`. This is just as fine as if you were initializing a member.

The C# syntax may make it look like the attribute is "outside" the class somehow, but this is not the case. The IL produced for this class is this:

```
.class private auto ansi beforefieldinit test.Test
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    .custom instance void test.Attr::.ctor(int32) = (
        01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    )
    // Fields
    .field private static literal int32 E = int32(0)

    ...

} // end of class test.Test
```

Had C# adopted a similar syntax, it might have looked something like this:

```
    class Test
    {
        attribute Attr(E);

        private const int E = 0;
    }
```

This would have emphasized the scope of the declaration, but it arguably wouldn't have been as clear. It becomes even less clear when attributes are applied to members (in IL, these directly follow the declaration).